# Why were I able to "check" the "disabled" checkbox on the live site and the data was successfully uploaded to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So I just visited one site, where it had the "disabled" checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
```

It couldn't be checked via mouse, so I decided to uncheck it via jQuery. Opened the console and wrote:

```
$('input[name="name"]').attr('checked', false);
```

It got unchecked. I thought, well, maybe it's just for me unchecked, but server will still get data from it as if it's checked.

So I uploaded my form and to my surprise the server behaved as if checkbox  was unchecked.

Why?

Comment: Because whoever wrote the server code is bad. A good server would not trust the client and would validate the data manually every time.

Comment: You better inspect exact request sent to server via your browser's developer console. Disabled inputs' values are not sent to server anyways. And I assume that this checkbox is just a part of UI and it's value is not handled on server.

Comment: How do you know what the server received, if you were just a visitor to the site? Or did you reproduce it on your own server? Because as glyuck said a control which is `disabled` (rather than `readonly`) should not be sent to the server at all, whether it's checked or not.

Comment: @IMSop It had an option that affected the form, and the form was submitted and the output was just like without this option. For example checkbox was responsible for prefix to the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It got unchecked. I thought, well, maybe it's just for me unchecked, but server will still get data from it as if it's checked.

Data from a form control will only be included in a submission if the control is successful:

- A disabled form control will not be successful control
- An unchecked checkbox will not be a successful control

You've just changed it from one state that would not submit data to a different state that would not submit data.

Comment: :( that was just an illusion then. huh, I thought of myself being such a hacker at that moment :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to inspect exact request sent to server via your browser's developer console, you will see all params actually sent to server. Since yout say checkbox is disabled, it's value IS NOT sent to server at all (whether it's checked or not). So I assume it's just a part of UI and it's value is not handled on server.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth remembering that the fields on a form rendered by a browser, and the values sent in a request to the server when you submit them, are basically only connected by convention. That is, there are strict standards on what the browser *should* do, but once the server has sent some HTML, the browser can theoretically do what it likes with it. In fact, you could look at the HTML directly, and create an HTTP request by hand (since it's a text-based protocol) which submitted whatever data you wanted.

This is important for developers to understand, because it means that **all data received from the user is untrusted** - no matter how you lay out your UI, which fields you ask the browser to hide, make read-only, etc, a user can send you whatever data you like, and it's up to you to detect that after it is received by the server.

So, while you're wrong in this case, you're right in general that you can use jQuery, or your browser's F12 debug tools, to manipulate fields on the form. In this case, it makes no difference, because an unchecked checkbox is not sent to the server even if it's not disabled (a design which is rather annoying for the author of the server-side code sometimes). But there are other situations where you can effect what is sent:

- removing the checkbox's `disabled` attribute, and setting the `checked` attribute (so that the value *is* sent to the server)
- changing the state of a control which is `readonly`, rather than `disabled` (since its value will always be sent)
- changing the `value` attribute of a hidden field, or setting it to visible and typing in it (e.g. try `jQuery('input[type=hidden]').attr('type', 'text');`)
- swapping out a `select` drop-down for a free-text `input` with the same `name` attribute, to choose values not in the list
- unsetting all the items in a radio-box group at once (something people actually do in real UIs, as an ugly kludge for "None of the above"/"Not selected yet")
- or even just look at the names of all the controls on the page, and create your own form with text fields with all of those names, and play with different values

So no, you didn't hack anything in this case, but yes, the basic idea is sound.